# Selecting rows based on two specific values in one column

Tags: r, select, subset

I'm new to R and this is my first question so apologies for errors.

I have a data frame where the rows are patient identifiers. The columns include age, sex, postcode, year of treatment (2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020). I want to make a new data frame of patients whose year of treatment is 2019 or 2020.

I've tried `newfile <- subset(df, year == c("2019", "2020"))` however for some reason not all of the correct rows make it into `newfile`. When I analyze the years independently in the original data frame, they do include the correct rows. When I do each year independently eg

```
newfile19 <- subset(df, year == "2019")
```

I get all the correct rows. So the problem seems to be a mistake I'm making when trying to get the two years' information.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or where some of the rows are dropping out along the way.

Many thanks.

Comment: Instead of `year == c("2019", "2020")` try `year %in% c("2019", "2020")`

Comment: Thank you very much, that has worked. I'm very grateful.